# Restrict user to accesss NON route URL's - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, restriction, url-shortener

I have a webapplication with the following route:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Mytest",
        url: "Admin/Dashboard/Index",
        defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", ID= "test" }
      );
```

Now when I go using `http://localhost:13/Admin/Dashboard/Index` it works, but `http://localhost:13/Dashboard/Index` also working.

But I would like, users can access `http://localhost:13/Admin/Dashboard/Index` ONLY. I need  when users access `http://localhost:13/Dashboard/Index` should returns 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define route to be ignored use [`RouteCollectionExtensions.IgnoreRoute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.routecollectionextensions.ignoreroute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) method:

```cs
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    // IgnoreRoute() added by default 
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.IgnoreRoute(url: "Dashboard/Index");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Mytest",
        url: "Admin/Dashboard/Index",
        defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", ID = "test" }
      );

    ... additional routes 

}
```